# using stable_sort and passing an object as the custom comparison operator

Tags: c++11, stl, c++14

This is part of an assignment, I am stuck at this instruction:

> Sort your randomly generated pool of schedules. 
>   Use std::stable_sort,
>   passing in an object of type schedule_compare as the custom comparison
>   operator.

---

**UPDATE:** I was checking [cppreference stable_srot()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/?kw=stable_sort), see method definition below:

```
void stable_sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator
 last,Compare comp );
```

, and it seems from what I understood is that you can only pass functions to the **last** argument (Compare comp) of the stable_sort() i.e:

However, in the instructions, it says that you need to pass an object of type `schedule_compare`. How is this possible ?

---

**This is my code below:**

```
struct schedule_compare
    {
        explicit schedule_compare(runtime_matrix const& m)
                : matrix_{m} { }

        bool operator()(schedule const& obj1, schedule const& obj2) {
            if (obj1.score > obj2.score)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    private:
        runtime_matrix const& matrix_;
    };

    auto populate_gene_pool(runtime_matrix const& matrix,
                            size_t const pool_size, random_generator& gen)
    {

        std::vector<schedule> v_schedule;
        v_schedule.reserve(pool_size);

        std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dis(0, matrix.machines() - 1);

        // 4. Sort your randomly generated pool of schedules. Use
        // std::stable_sort, passing in an object of type
        // schedule_compare as the custom comparison operator.

        std::stable_sort(begin(v_schedule), end(v_schedule), ???)

        return; v_schedule;
    }
```

Comment: And what problems do you have with the code you show? If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I thought it was obvious, anyway, thanks for telling me. ill update the question now

Comment: Best to always be explicit. :)

Comment: On an unrelated note, the result of a comparison is a boolean `true` or `false`. Meaning your `schedule_compare::operator()` function doesn't need the `if` statement. All it needs to do is `return obj1.score > obj2.score;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For algorithm functions that accepts a "function" (like [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)) you can pass anything that can be *called* as a function.

For example a pointer to a global, namespace or `static` member function. *Or* you can pass a function-like object instance (i.e. an instance of a class that has a function call operator), also known as a *functor* object.

This is simply done by creating a temporary object, and passing it to the `std::stable_sort` (in your case):

```
std::stable_sort(begin(v_schedule), end(v_schedule), schedule_compare(matrix));
```

Since the `schedule_compare` structure have a function call operator (the `operator()` member function) it can generally be treated like any other function, including being "called".

Comment: damn, that was deep. Ok, Just to make sure I understood how this works, so each element of `v_schedule` will eventually be compared with `matrix` and based on that it will be sorted, correct? ps: `matrix_runtime` has  `std::vector<std::size_t> elements_;` as private.